# Accessing a config var from browser JavaScript (not Node) in Heroku

Tags: javascript, github, heroku, environment-variables, github-api

I would like to get info from GitHub API from browser JS on my website hosted on Heroku.

I have thought of two ways to do this:

1. Hide an API key in a config var and read the config var in JS

   I went with this option and I ran into an issue:

   To hide the API key I would need to make a config var in the settings of my project, then read it using **browser (not Node)** JavaScript. I currently am stuck on reading the config var using JS.
2. Through a GitHub workflow run on push (or whatever event)

   This is an advantage because I can read the repo from inside a workflow and not need to use a key (I think). Then the workflow would write data to a file on the website.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to do. You're trying to get the *GitHub API Key* from your Heroku app settings using just client-side JS?

Comment: Is it not possible to do this?

Comment: If you're answering "yes" for my question, then it *is* possible. You'll need a server-side language like NodeJS or PHP to read the environment variables then output them for client-side JS to read. [See this question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65260762/unable-to-access-api-key-in-heroku-config-vars-from-javascript-app).

Comment: I don't know if I'm supposed to do this, but I flagged my question as a duplicate. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to access API key in Heroku Config Vars from Javascript app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65260762/unable-to-access-api-key-in-heroku-config-vars-from-javascript-app)

Comment: Thanks for your help too, yes that question helped!